# Update pairs of shiny widgets which affect each other

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below in which the initial subset happens from the 1st input with the names. Then the available values should pass to the other four inputs and to the table.

I want the values of the other 4 inputs to be updated based  on the choice of the 1st but also when for example I select min or max value the min and max dates to be re-subseted and vice versa.

Only the 1st input  should keep the same amount of all names every time.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
# Load necessary libraries
library(DT)

# Creating a sample dataframe
set.seed(123)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date("2023-12-31"), by = "days")
numeric_values <- sample(1:100, length(dates), replace = TRUE)
names <- rep(c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"), length.out = length(dates))

df <- data.frame(Date = dates, Numeric = numeric_values, Name = names)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput("namePicker", "Select Name:", choices = unique(df$Name),selected = unique(df$Name)[1], multiple = TRUE),
      uiOutput("numeric1"),
      uiOutput("numeric2"),
      uiOutput("date1"),
      uiOutput("date2")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Filter data based on selected names
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    req(input$namePicker)
    df_subset <- df[df$Name %in% input$namePicker, ]
    
    return(df_subset)
  })
  
  # Render the filtered data table
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(filtered_data(), options = list(pageLength = 10))  # Customize datatable appearance if needed
  })
  
  # Render numeric range inputs dynamically
  output$numeric1 <- renderUI({
    numericInput("minNumeric", "Min Numeric Value:", min = min(df$Numeric), max = max(df$Numeric), value = min(df$Numeric))
  })
  output$numeric2 <- renderUI({
    numericInput("maxNumeric", "Max Numeric Value:", min = min(df$Numeric), max = max(df$Numeric), value = max(df$Numeric))
  })
  # Render date range inputs dynamically
  output$date1 <- renderUI({
    dateInput("minDate", "Min Date:", min = min(df$Date), max = max(df$Date), value = min(df$Date))
  })
  output$date2 <- renderUI({
    dateInput("maxDate", "Max Date:", min = min(df$Date), max = max(df$Date), value = max(df$Date))
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR All inputs influence each other, which was done with `oberve` which depends on the final filtered data. There are two filtered datasets, an init one and one connected with numeric/Date inputs. The update of the inputs is turned off when the selection is empty (with if).

When I find out this question, the first connected topic is [Hierarchical Filtering](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.0/doc/html/filter/filter_what_is_hierarchy_filter.htm) as an alternative strategy for dependent filters/selections.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'shinydashboard'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     box
library(shinyWidgets)
# Load necessary libraries
library(DT)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'DT'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     dataTableOutput, renderDataTable

# Creating a sample dataframe
set.seed(123)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date("2023-12-31"), by = "days")
numeric_values <- sample(1:100, length(dates), replace = TRUE)
names <- rep(c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"), length.out = length(dates))

df <- data.frame(Date = dates, Numeric = numeric_values, Name = names)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput("namePicker", "Select Name:", choices = unique(df$Name), selected = unique(df$Name)[1], multiple = TRUE),
      uiOutput("inputs")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Filter data based on selected names
  filtered_data <- eventReactive(input$namePicker, {
    df_subset <- df[df$Name %in% input$namePicker, ]
    df_subset
  })

  # Render numeric range inputs dynamically
  output$inputs <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      numericInput(
        "minNumeric",
        "Min Numeric Value:",
        value = min(filtered_data()$Numeric),
        min = min(filtered_data()$Numeric),
        max = max(filtered_data()$Numeric)
      ),
      numericInput(
        "maxNumeric",
        "Max Numeric Value:",
        value = max(filtered_data()$Numeric),
        min = min(filtered_data()$Numeric),
        max = max(filtered_data()$Numeric)
      ),
      dateInput(
        "minDate",
        "Min Date:",
        min = min(filtered_data()$Date),
        max = max(filtered_data()$Date),
        value = min(filtered_data()$Date)
      ),
      dateInput(
        "maxDate",
        "Max Date:",
        min = min(filtered_data()$Date),
        max = max(filtered_data()$Date),
        value = max(filtered_data()$Date)
      )
    )
  })

  filtered_data_full <- eventReactive(
    list(input$minNumeric, input$maxNumeric, input$minDate, input$maxDate),
    {
      df_subset <- subset(filtered_data(), Numeric >= input$minNumeric & Numeric <= input$maxNumeric & Date >= input$minDate & Date <= input$maxDate)
      df_subset
    },
    ignoreInit = TRUE
  )

  observe({
    if (NROW(filtered_data_full())) {
      updateNumericInput(
        session,
        "maxNumeric",
        "Max Numeric Value:",
        value = max(filtered_data_full()$Numeric),
        min = min(filtered_data_full()$Numeric),
        max = max(filtered_data_full()$Numeric)
      )
      updateNumericInput(
        session,
        "minNumeric",
        "Min Numeric Value:",
        min = min(filtered_data_full()$Numeric),
        max = max(filtered_data_full()$Numeric),
        value = min(filtered_data_full()$Numeric)
      )
      updateDateInput(
        session,
        "minDate",
        "Min Date:",
        min = min(filtered_data_full()$Date),
        max = max(filtered_data_full()$Date),
        value = min(filtered_data_full()$Date)
      )
      updateDateInput(
        session,
        "maxDate",
        "Max Date:",
        min = min(filtered_data_full()$Date),
        max = max(filtered_data_full()$Date),
        value = max(filtered_data_full()$Date)
      )
    }
  })

  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(filtered_data_full(), options = list(pageLength = 10))
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4962
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: this Q is based on your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77739807/display-text-message-based-on-dynamic-date-inputs-in-a-shiny-app

Comment: issue with pickerinput() related to your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77741485/the-none-choice-from-shinywidgets-pickerinput-seems-not-to-work

Answer (score 1):

please check below solution.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
# Load necessary libraries
library(DT)

# Creating a sample dataframe
set.seed(123)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date("2023-12-31"), by = "days")
numeric_values <- sample(1:100, length(dates), replace = TRUE)
names <- rep(c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"), length.out = length(dates))

df <- data.frame(Date = dates, Numeric = numeric_values, Name = names)
```

I simplified your server a bit, it is not efficient way to create inputs in server and call uioutput in UI part, you can write directly in UI or just create one render value for all ui inputs.

And also if you want to update your 4 inputs depending on your namePicker input, then you need to specify as NULL for values, and you will update them in server

```
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput("namePicker", "Select Name:", choices = unique(df$Name),selected = unique(df$Name)[1], multiple = TRUE),
      numericInput("minNumeric", "Min Numeric Value:", value = NULL),
      numericInput("maxNumeric", "Max Numeric Value:", value = NULL),
      dateInput("minDate", "Min Date:", value = NULL),
      dateInput("maxDate", "Max Date:", value = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table")
    )
  )
)
```

I used two observeEvent in Server, first: to update minnumeric and maxnumeric inputs according to what you choose for pickerName, and
secondly: as I understand correctly mindate and maxdate according to what other variable has been chosen. as you see whatever you chose in picker name it will automatically update input values

```
# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$namePicker, {
    # Filter the managers based on the selected country
    filtered <- df[df$Name %in% input$namePicker, ]
    
    # Update the choices for the numeric input
    updateNumericInput(session, "minNumeric", min = min(filtered$Numeric), max = max(filtered$Numeric), value = min(filtered$Numeric))
    updateNumericInput(session, "maxNumeric", min = max(filtered$Numeric), max = max(filtered$Numeric), value = max(filtered$Numeric))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(c(input$namePicker, input$minNumeric, input$maxNumeric), {
    # Filter the managers based on the selected country
    filtered <- df[df$Name %in% input$namePicker & df$Numeric >= input$minNumeric & df$Numeric <= input$maxNumeric, ]
    
    # Update the choices for the numeric input
    updateDateInput(session, "minDate", min = min(filtered$Date), max = max(filtered$Date), value = min(filtered$Date))
    updateDateInput(session, "maxDate", min = max(filtered$Date), max = max(filtered$Date), value = max(filtered$Date))
  })
  
  
  
  # Filter data based on selected names
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    req(input$namePicker)
    df_subset <- df[df$Name %in% input$namePicker &
                      df$Numeric >= input$minNumeric &
                      df$Numeric <= input$maxNumeric &
                      df$Date >= input$minDate &
                      df$Date <= input$maxDate,
                    ]
    
    return(df_subset)
  })
  
  # Render the filtered data table
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(filtered_data(), options = list(pageLength = 10))  # Customize datatable appearance if needed
  })
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I hope, this solution will help you in your project, if you have any question, please let me know.

Comment: when you change min and max numerics, dates change but when you change min and max dates the min and max numerics are not affected